# Trying to return char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I realize the way I am approaching this is wrong, but I don't know why.
I am very new to C++/programming in general.
I want my program to do the following.
If I cin "setwanted joe" I want it to store joe into a char array. I have it so I can succesfully seperate and cout joe, but I am can't return the char array from the function.
Here's my example code.

```
char * GETNAME (char *searchinput, char*searchtext)
{
    char returnname[64];
    int starter=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        if (*searchinput == *searchtext)
        {
            searchinput++;
            searchtext++;

        }
        if (*searchinput == ' ')
        {
            searchinput++;
            searchtext++;
        }
        if (*searchinput!='\0' && *searchinput!= *searchtext && *searchinput != ' ')
        {
            returnname[starter] = *searchinput;
            starter++;
            searchinput++;
            searchtext++;
        }
        if (*searchinput=='\0')
        {
            returnname[starter]='\0';
            cout << "Char Array to Return: " << returnname << endl;
            return returnname;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the function I made to try to return the name from the char array.
Here is the code I was using to call the function.

```
char Recv[256];
cin >> Recv;
char * wantedname = new char[64];
wantedname = GETNAME(Recv,"setwanted");
cout << "Returned Name: " << wantedname << endl;
```

Thanks for reading/your patience I know this is messy.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a `char array` rather than a `string`?  It's not inherently wrong, I'm just asking to be sure you have a good reason for doing so...

Comment: Please don't edit the title to include the word RESOLVED. If the question has been answered, you can accept one of the answers below to mark the question as resolved and award some bonus reputation to the wonderful person who helped clear up your doubts. :-)

Comment: Returning a reference/pointer to a local variable has undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::array`, `std::vector` or `std::string` (in case of array of characters) to easily return an array of items. You're code invokes *undefined behavior* due to returning a pointer to a local temporary object. I prefer this

```
std::string GETNAME(const std::string &searchinput,const std::string &searchtext)
{
    std::string returnname;

    ...

    return returnname;
}
```